# Proving statement in probability about two sequences of random events and their infinite occurrences

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-limit-theorems, borel-cantelli-lemmas

This statement in probability seems definitely true, but I cannot work out how to prove it.

Let $X, Y$ be measure spaces, $U \subset X$, $V \subset Y$ open sets, and $f: X \times Y \to X$ a measurable function. We then define two sequences of random variables in $X$ and $Y$ accordingly: Let $(y^k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables in $Y$, such that $\mathbb{P}(y^k \in V) = p > 0$, and define $(x^k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \subset X$ via
$$
x^{k+1} := f(x^k, y^k), \qquad \mbox{where } k \in \mathbb{N},  \mbox{ and }  x^0 \in X \mbox{ is given}.
$$
The statement I want to prove is then:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left( (x^k \in U) \cap (y^k \in V) \mbox{ infinitely often } \; | \; x^k \in U \mbox{ infinitely often} \right) = 1.
$$

Any suggestions on how to prove this would be appreciated. I have tried to consider Borel-Cantelli type results, but without pairwise independence of $(x^k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, I wonder if that is a dead-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I also thought that this must be true, but it isn’t, actually. Consider $f$ such that $f(x,y)=a\not\in U$ for $(x\in U)\cap(y\in V)$ and $f(a,y)=a$ for all $y\in Y$. Then $(x^k\in U)\cap(y^k\in V)$ at most once, and yet $x^k\in U$ can occur infinitely often (albeit with probability $0$, as it requires $y^k\not\in V$ whenever $x^k\in U$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Being slightly naive to probability and measure theory, I hadn't considered that one could condition on an event of zero probability, as "$x^k \in U$ infinitely often" would be in this case. Given this answer, I guess a refined question would be whether it's the case that either the original statement holds or $\mathbb{P}(x^k \in U \mbox{ infinitely often}) = 0$? I would think this is true, but perhaps this Q would be more appropriate for a new post.